# Не получается получить данные из массива $_SESSION

Tags: php

Делаю регистрацию на Redbean php. Возникла проблема: не могу получить данные из глобальной переменной `session`. Я ищу пользователя по введённому логину и создаю ключ `['user']` с пользователем. При `var_dump($_SESSION['user'])` все значения имеются , но когда я хочу вывести отдельно (`echo $_SESSION['user']->login;`) ничего не выводится.

Вот код авторизации, где я присваиваю `user`

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    require '../db.php';
    $data = $_POST;

    $login = $data['login'];
    $password = $data['password'];

    //Login user
    if( isset($data['signin']) ){
        $user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', [$login]);
        if( $user ){
            if( password_verify($password, $user->password) ){
                $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    
                header("Location: ../profile.php");
            }else{
                $_SESSION['message'] = "Не верный пароль!";
                header("Location: ../index.php");
            }
        }else{
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Пользователь не найден!";
            header("Location: ../index.php");
        }
    }
```

А вот так я вывожу логин в личном кабинете

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'db.php';
?>

<h1><?php echo $_SESSION['user']->login; ?></h1>
```

Вроде бы всё правильно делаю, но всё равно ничего не выводится. Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: есть ли у вас ошибки в консоли? или просто ничего не выводится?

Comment: Нет ошибок в консоли нет . Просто ничего не выводится

Comment: Только вот эти три   Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
profile.php:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
styles.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: а что выводится, если оставить `<h1><?php echo $_SESSION['user']?></h1>?`

Comment: Выводится во это Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string in

Comment: А можно спросить, какое отношение к этому вопросу имеют javascript, html, css и вёрстка?

Comment: Ну, к строке он это привести не может, а если вывести так: `<h1><?php var_dump($_SESSION['user']); ?></h1>`?

Comment: Выводится полностью весь массив с ключами login, password, email и id , но мне нужно вывести только login

Comment: а если вывести так echo `$_SESSION['user']['login']`?

Comment: @Ипатьев вывод то в html, лучше тег оставить или я не прав?

Comment: Ну то есть если выводить не в HTML, а в PDF, то что-то изменится? И нужное свойство в объекте **сразу найдется**, да?

Comment: Проблема возникает из-за того что объект в переменной сессии не может быть [де-сериализован](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010427/php-php-incomplete-class-object-with-my-session-data). Рекомендуется хранить в сессии базовые типы и делать десериализацию вручную из строки, и не хранить объекты в этой переменной (тем более объект из устаревшей библиотеки Redbean)